# How to display list based on user identity name ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to display a list based on the `UserID` I get, but it seems like it does not show any list. I want to know where am I missing it wrong or what am I suppose to do.

Example table - Play

```
       UserID    | Balls          
      -----------+--------------
       thokozani | Soccer ball 5   
       thokozani | Soccer ball 10  
       fhulu     | Tennis ball
```

Code

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var UserId = User.Identity.Name;
    return View(db.Plays.Where(x => x.UserID == UserId).ToList());
}
```

Comment: Did you make sure that User.Identity.Name matches the UserID of a record from your Play table? What does your view look like? Please provide a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, you had an use [Authorize] attribute on method.